# .bash_profile function run operation on same file directory

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have the following function in my .bash_profile:

```
function GIT_BRANCH() {

    STATUS="\$(git status 2> /dev/null)";

    if [[ ! ${STATUS} ]]; then
            if [[ ! ${STATUS} = *"working tree clean"* ]]; then
                    echo "not clean repo";
            else
                    echo "clean repo";
            fi
    else
            echo "not a repo";
    fi

}
```

If i run the command like this:

```
echo $(git status 2> /dev/null);
echo $(pwd);
```

then the command is unfortunately not executed in the same directory in which I am currently in the shell.

I tried to solve the problem as in the following example.

```
STATUS="\$(git status 2> /dev/null)";
```

This works fine as long as I output the variable with echo. If I understand this correctly, only the string is stored in the variable and the command is not executed when comparing. How do I get the return value of the command stored in STATUS and run the command in the same shell anyway?

EDIT:

I use the function in PS1. If i try:

```
function GIT_BRANCH() {
    STATUS="\$(git status 2> /dev/null)";
    echo ${STATUS};
    TEST="\$(pwd)";
    echo ${TEST};
}

export PS1="$(COLOR "199")\u$RESET_ALL$(COLOR "45") \h \w$RESET_ALL $(COLOR "199")$(GIT_BRANCH $DIRE)$RESET_ALL\n$(COLOR "199")$ >$RESET_ALL "
```

Then all works fine and i get the current directory. But thats don't work if i try to use this information in the function itself, like in the examples I've posted before.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: The command *is* executed in the same directory. What makes you think it isn't? Why did you write `STATUS="\$(git status 2> /dev/null)"`, which sets `STATUS` to the string `$(git status 2> /dev/null)`, and not `STATUS="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"`, which sets `STATUS` to the output of `git status`, and is AFAICT what you need to make the function work (except that you should use git's porcelain commands do avoid parsing output meant for humans)?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case when I try it with echo $(pwd), no matter which directory I'm in, it will always output the same.

Comment: This should not happen. You may have something weird in your configuration but I can't think of what would cause this. What's the output when you run this? `cd /; set -x; cd /tmp; pwd; echo $(pwd); set +x`

Comment: If i write the same script in a file like test.sh and run this file in the terminal all works normal. For example: 

#!/bin/bash

STATUS=$(git status 2> /dev/null);
echo ${STATUS};

The STATUS variable has the correct output as value. But i use the function in PS1, then the function run the git command not in the same directory that I'm currently in.

Comment: _How_ are you using the function in `PS1`?

Comment: export PS1="$(COLOR "199")\u$RESET_ALL$(COLOR "45") \h \w$RESET_ALL $(COLOR "199")$(GIT_BRANCH)$RESET_ALL\n$(COLOR "199")$ >$RESET_ALL "

Comment: You function is evaluated exactly once, when you set PS1 and then never again. Use single quotes rather than double quotes when assigning the value to PS1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with quoting.

You are essentially setting your `PS1` variable like

```
PS1="$(myfunction)"
```

(exporting `PS1` is not needed as it's the current shell that's using it, only).

This will call `myfunction` at the time of assigning to `PS1`, and the function will never be called again.

Instead, you should use

```
PS1='$(myfunction)'
```

This would cause `myfunction` to be called each time the prompt is being displayed.

No special quoting is needed in the function itself.

---

Your function:

```
function GIT_BRANCH() {

    STATUS="\$(git status 2> /dev/null)";

    if [[ ! ${STATUS} ]]; then
            if [[ ! ${STATUS} = *"working tree clean"* ]]; then
                    echo "not clean repo";
            else
                    echo "clean repo";
            fi
    else
            echo "not a repo";
    fi

}
```

This could be rewritten as

```
GIT_BRANCH () {
    local status="$( git status --porcelain 2>&1 )"

    case "$status" in
        *"fatal: not a git repository"*)
            echo 'Not a repo' ;;
        "")
            echo 'Clean repo' ;;
        *)
            echo 'Not clean repo' ;;
    esac
}
```

Or, using `if` statements:

```
GIT_BRANCH () {
    local status="$( git status --porcelain 2>&1 )"

    if [[ "$status" == *"fatal: not a git repository"* ]]; then
        echo 'Not a repo'
    elif [[ -z "$status" ]]; then
        echo 'Clean repo'
    else
        echo 'Not clean repo'
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PROMPT_COMMAND parameter

```
alux@deb904:~$ PROMPT_COMMAND=pwd
/home/alux
alux@deb904:~$ cd /tmp
/tmp
alux@deb904:/tmp$
```

With your function :

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND=GIT_BRANCH
```

Comment: That would run before displaying each new prompt, but it would not place the output _in_ the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter PS1 is a static string, which can be customized by inserting a number of backslash-escaped special characters (\u, \d, \$, ...). Only these tags are dynamic.

```
alux@deb904:~$ echo $PS1
\u@\h:\w\$
alux@deb904:~$ ps1="$PS1"
```

when PS1 is valuated with a command (PS1=$(pwd) or PS1=`pwd`), PS1 is valued with the return of this command.

```
alux@deb904:~$ PS1="$(pwd) > "
/home/alux > echo $PS1
/home/alux >
/home/alux > cd /tmp
/home/alux > echo $PS1
/home/alux >
/home/alux > pwd
/tmp
```

The PROMPT_COMMAND parameter can be validated to contain a command line executed before the value of PS1 is displayed.
We use a function, it is more appropriate.

```
/home/alux > PS1=$ps1
alux@deb904:~$ myprompt(){ pwd; echo " > "; }
alux@deb904:~$ COMMAND_PROMPT=myprompt
/home/alux
>
alux@deb904:~$
```

To avoid going back to the line, use echo -n.

```
/home/alux
>
alux@deb904:~$ myprompt(){ echo -n "$(pwd) > "; }
/home/alux > alux@deb904:~$ cd /tmp
/tmp > alux@deb904:/tmp$
```

We can delete the value of PS1.

```
/tmp > alux@deb904:/tmp$PS1=
/tmp >
```

But we do not have special characters escaped from the backslash.

```
/tmp >  myprompt(){ echo -n "$(pwd) \u \h  > "; }
/tmp \u \h >
```

Then we can use other parameter ($USER, $HOSTNAME, ...)

```
/tmp \u \h >  myprompt(){ echo -n "$(pwd) $USER $HOSTNAME  > "; }
/tmp alux deb906 >
```

The value of PROMPT_COMMAND is executed before the display of the PS1 value. So we can use PROMPT_COMMAND to modify PS1.

```
/tmp alux deb906  > myprompt(){ PS1=$(echo -n "$(pwd) (\h) > "); }
/tmp (deb904) > echo $PS1
/tmp (deb904) >
/tmp (deb904) > cd ~
/home/alux (deb904) > echo $PS1
/home/alux (deb904) >
/home/alux (deb904) > PROMPT_COMMAND=
/home/alux (deb904) > PS1=$ps1
alux@deb904:~$
```

Now in your .bash_profile :

```
function GIT_BRANCH() {
  local status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
  local msg
  if [ "${status}" ]; then
        if [ ! "${status}" = *"working tree clean"* ]; then
                msg="not clean repo"
        else
                msg="clean repo"
        fi
  else
        msg="not a repo"
  fi
  PS1="\u \h \w ${msg}\n\$ "
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=GIT_BRANCH
```

Answer (score -1):

Use eval :

```
function GIT_BRANCH() {

  STATUS="\$(git status 2> /dev/null)";

  if [ "$(eval echo ${STATUS})" ]; then

        if [ ! $(eval echo ${STATUS}) = *"working tree clean"* ]; then
                echo "not clean repo";
        else
                echo "clean repo";
        fi
  else
        echo "not a repo";
  fi

}
```

Or another additional function :

```
function STATUS(){
  git status 2> /dev/null
}
function GIT_BRANCH() {
  if [ "$(STATUS)" ]; then
    …
  fi
}
```

Comment: If i create a new function: function GET_PWD() { pwd } then i have the same problem. No matter in which directory I am, the value is always the path of the user directory, in this directory is the .bash_profile.

Comment: When my STATUS variable contains the string like STATUS="\$(git status 2> /dev/null)"; and i echo the value, only then i get the informations from right directory currently.